# Didn't find a way referring to URL fetched itself through term in searchbox using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

The site is  http://www.moneycontrol.com. I aimed at finding live stock prices of companies(I have a list) I would put in search box. The site automatically takes to the URL of a company whenever you search for it.For instance if I type Wipro in search box it automatically took to this URL http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/computers-software/wipro/W

First I will explain what I have tried for 
I have followed a standard format of search i.e

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bsoup


soup=Bsoup(html)
fread=open("ListOfScrips.csv") # List of company names
reader=csv.reader(fread)
compdict=dict((rows[0],rows[2]) for rows in reader)
#print compdict
complist=[k for k in compdict.values()]
for l in complist: 
    l.replace(" ","+") #If spaces in company name replace with +
    #url=url+l
    url=url+"#q="+l
```

I tried some other ways which are mentioned in stack overflow, But unable to actually find that automatically fetched URL.

Please someone guide me how can I search in a search bar with companies from my list and get that URL for parsing elements.

Comment: are the links to the companies always the same, do the number of companies in your list impede you to have a dict of `{company: url}`? if you could have a list of urls you can download the html (with `requests` or `urllib2`) and then parse it with `BeautifulSoup`. but if you need to put each company in the search box then you should use a webdriver like `Selenium`, `BeautifulSoup` by itself is only a library to pull out data from HTML o XML files, it can't handle dynamic content.

Comment: @odradek Yes they are perhaps the same always, the links to companies, any other library that could fetch the URL of the company that is being searched for????

Comment: if you want to open `http://www.moneycontrol.com` then fill in a search box with the name of a company, then click "Search" and only then parse the HTML you need to use a webdriver like `Selenium`, see http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: then again, if you have a list of URLs you can download the HTML directly and then parse it with `BeautifulSoup` you can use the `requests` lib which is very easy to use, but you need a list of URLs. (docs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)